# React, Firebase - signInWithEmailAndPassword - cannot use the user variable outside .then() block

Tags: reactjs, firebase, async-await, firebase-authentication

I am trying to set up a react-app which uses firebase authentication only with email and password.

When you have a look at googles documentation for signing in with email and password, you find the following code:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    var user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
  });
```

In my application, I get `auth` and the submitted email / password via `action.formState.values.email` / `action.formState.values.password`.

`initialState` is the default user object, which I am then trying to modify and return for the function `sessionReducer`.

I have implemented it the following way:

```
import * as actionTypes from 'actions';
import { auth } from '../firebase';


const initialState = {
  loggedIn: false,
  user: {
    first_name: 'First Name',
    last_name: 'Second Name',
    email: 'email@email.com',
    avatar: '/images/avatars/avatar_11.png',
    bio: 'Titel/Bio',
    role: 'ADMIN'
  }
};

const sessionReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {

    case actionTypes.SESSION_LOGIN: {

      auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(action.formState.values.email, action.formState.values.password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
          // Signed in
          var user = userCredential.user;
          return user;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Print error message
        });

      
      // ------ Cannot access user object from firebase here ------ //

      return {
        loggedIn: true,
        user: {
          ...initialState.user,
          email: user.email // <- Here I need the Email out of the user object from firebase
        }
      };
    }
  }
};


export default sessionReducer;
```

When I print the user object from firebase directly in the `.then()` block, I get everything I need but as soon as I want to use this user variable outside, after the the then block block, I don't have access to it.

I think the problem is, that the `return` statement runs too early... The firebase-call has not yet finished but the return statement already tries to access the user variable from firebase.

If you need any more information, just ask as I am not sure how much I have to provide...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with Firebase Auth.  You're going to have to learn how to use promises in Javascript (those objects that you call `then` and `catch` on).  Since promises indicate the execution of asynchronous work, you won't be able to use them at all in a reducer.  You'll need to move async work elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As Doug mentioned in the comment you can't use `async` code in a pure `redux`. To make your code work try to use something like [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) or [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/). This example should explain a little bit how it works:

```js
function makeASandwich(forPerson, secretSauce) {
  return {
    type: 'MAKE_SANDWICH',
    forPerson,
    secretSauce,
  };
}

function apologize(fromPerson, toPerson, error) {
  return {
    type: 'APOLOGIZE',
    fromPerson,
    toPerson,
    error,
  };
}

function withdrawMoney(amount) {
  return {
    type: 'WITHDRAW',
    amount,
  };
}

// Even without middleware, you can dispatch an action:
store.dispatch(withdrawMoney(100));

// But what do you do when you need to start an asynchronous action,
// such as an API call, or a router transition?

// Meet thunks.
// A thunk in this context is a function that can be dispatched to perform async
// activity and can dispatch actions and read state.
// This is an action creator that returns a thunk:
function makeASandwichWithSecretSauce(forPerson) {
  // We can invert control here by returning a function - the "thunk".
  // When this function is passed to `dispatch`, the thunk middleware will intercept it,
  // and call it with `dispatch` and `getState` as arguments.
  // This gives the thunk function the ability to run some logic, and still interact with the store.
  return function(dispatch) {
    return fetchSecretSauce().then(
      (sauce) => dispatch(makeASandwich(forPerson, sauce)),
      (error) => dispatch(apologize('The Sandwich Shop', forPerson, error)),
    );
  };
}
```

What we are doing here is just enabling redux to handle `async` code.